# Upgrade to Knockout 3.0.0, Templates/Custom Binding Handlers no longer work

Tags: javascript

The following code no longer works when upgrading my code base to Knockout 3.0.0. Can anyone provide a workaround?

Code referencing the template:

```
<div data-bind="clientFormItemTemplate: {foreach: clients}"/>
```

Template code:

```
<script type="text/html" id="clientFormItemTemplate">
<li>    
<div style="float: left; padding-left: 5px;">
  <span class="font-normal" data-bind="text: displayName"></span>     
</div>
<div class="clear"/>
</li>
</script>
```

Custom binding handler for template:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clientFormItemTemplate = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) 
    {            
        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.init.apply (this, arguments);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) 
    {            
        return (ko.bindingHandlers.template.update.apply (this, arguments));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the default `template` binding? One reason I could think of (if this is not the whole code) might be "2. Bindings are now refreshed independently" (from [Knockout v3 Upgrade Notes](http://knockoutjs.com/upgrade-notes/v3.0.0.html))

Comment: I am not using the default template binding because I am migrating a Flex application and trying to mimic Flex's ability to create custom components. My custom binding handler code also includes handlers for click and double click (they're not shown in the code snippet) which I attach in the afterRender event. Prior to asking my question, I reviewed the upgrade notes and noticed the section on bindings refreshing independently but I couldn't make the connection because I only have one binding (i.e. a foreach binding).

Comment: OK, got it. I noticed another thing. The `template` binding takes a `name` parameter in addition to `foreach` to identify the template it should use. Maybe you need to add this property to the `valueAccessor()` in your custom binding. However, if the same code already worked, that will not be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `name` property for the `template` binding. You can add it in your custom binding like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clientFormItemTemplate = (function() {
    function getModifiedValue(valueAccessor) {
        return function() {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            value.name = 'clientFormItemTemplate';
            return value;
        };
    }

    return {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
            return ko.bindingHandlers.template.init(element, getModifiedValue(valueAccessor), allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
            return ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, getModifiedValue(valueAccessor), allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
        }
    };
})();
```

Here is a workling [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pz6Sj/) (with Knockout 3.0.0).